# CAS extension is not present while install GLPI

Tags: xampp, php-7.2

I'm trying to setup the GLPI application. but getting missing extension **"CAS extension is not present".**

I've find out the phpCAS at https://apereo.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CASC/pages/103252517/phpCAS but not able to get dll of the extension.

I'm using xmapp in windows 10.

How can resolve the issue?
[image: GLPI Setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Install CAS extension for GLPI:**

- Open composer.json file and **"apereo/phpcas"="^1.3"** in require.
- Run composer update command in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but you don't need to install a perfectly working GLPI instance.
Since you're using XAMPP and Windows 10 this should be a testing environment and you probably won't need CAS Authentication on it.
If so, best chance is you using a virtual linux server  and you won't have any trouble installing PHP CAS support.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

simply type

```
sudo apt install php-cas
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Additionally, you should consider that `apt install` won't work on Windows

Comment: Ohh gosh. Sorry. Yeah you are totally right.
I thought i was on ubuntu site and it was linux issue. Thank you for cathing that. Mods could delete my embarassing post :)

Answer (score -1):

centOS

the required extension is in the REMI repository

1. yum repo-pkgs remi list php*cas
2. yum repo-pkgs remi install php-pear-CAS